# Amcharts - Checkbox legend

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to find if amcharts has a facility to have legends as checkboxes just like highcharts does. Some examples in here -

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174158/in-highchart-legend-want-to-bring-checkbox-at-start
    http://jsfiddle.net/lukelarsen/yHGS9/9/
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.co.nz/2009/10/linechart-with-checkbox-legend.html
```

I tried to put checkboxes outside the chart & add listeners & so forth. it gets complicated. So wondering if anyone has had this requirement & has managed to implement it?

Any help would be highly helpful.

Comment: The AmCharts legend works like a checkbox already.

Comment: Hello Gerric - Thank you. I agree it has the check box effect. I'd like to have a check box itself just for better user friendliness. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

First we have to add eventlisteners to create the boxes everytime the chart redraws. (this is necessary because the checkboxes are child elements of the legend and the legend is recreated everytime sth happens with the chart)

```
chart.addListener("init", function() {
    chart.addListener("drawn", createCheckboxes);
    chart.legend.addListener("showItem", createCheckboxes);
    chart.legend.addListener("hideItem", createCheckboxes);
}
```

Then we're creating the one checkbox for each legend entry.

```
function createCheckboxes() {
    var legend = chart.legend.legendData;
    var div = $("<div style='position:absolute; top: 10px'></div>");
    for(var i = 0; i < legend.length; i++) {
        div.append("<input style='float: left; "
            + "position: absolute; top:" + legend[i].legendEntry.y + "px' "
            + "type='checkbox'" + (legend[i].hidden ? " " : " checked ")
            + "onclick=toggleItem(" + i + ")></input>");
    }
    div.appendTo($(chart.legend.div));
}
```

The last step is to handle the click event on the checkboxes.

```
var toggleItem = function(i) {
    chart.legend.clickLabel(chart.legend.legendData[i], event);
}
```

That's it. [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bErxOy?editors=001)

Comment: That's what i needed. You are a star@gerric